# Query a time range from a text[] column that holds values in HH:MM format

Tags: postgresql

In my DB schema i have a table with a a `text[]` column that holds time values in the format `HH:MM`. (The reason i don't use a `time[]` column is a limitation in the ORM i use).

Now what i want to do is query the table with a time range (e.g. `13:00` - `16:30`) and get all the rows where at least 1 values from that column is contained within that range.

What i thought about doing, but couldn't figure out how to do (if even possible) is to create an index for that column casting the values to type `time`, and then using some form of `tsrange(<time-start>, <time-end>, []) && <column_name>`.
But i'm stuck at creating the index and not sure if that's possible as i'm quite a novice when it comes to PostgreSQL/DBs in general.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Could you plase show your table DDL and a couple of actual recirds - make a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk). Version of .PostgreSQL? Will the times ever go over midnight?

Comment: Why not? : 1) Have a start and end time fields of type `time`  or 2) Better yet make the field a `tsrange`.